# a.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/, "0$1")？

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have occurred a function as follows:

```
function format(str){
            return str.toString().replace(/^(\d)$/,"0$1");
}
```

The function of format is format time, if the hour or minute have only one symbol,
the result will return

```
1 -> 01
2 ->02
```

The question is that I don't know the meaning of 0$1?
Thank you.

Comment: `$1 == (\d)`, it is the first capture group.

Comment: $1 is the first match.

Comment: Note that the specific problem can be solved without regex: `return ('0'+str).slice(-2);`

Comment: @DavidHedlund Depends on what inputs the function is designed to take.  If you pass it "I am a fish", you'll get back "I am a fish".  With yours, you'd get "sh".

Comment: @DavidHedlund Expect when `str > 99`

Comment: @James: granted, if you want a format time function to support "I am a fish" o'clock, you'd have to update the code to something that could cater to that scenario. The above suggestion was based on the context of the question. It could easily be adapted to account for `str.length` if you really do need to support fish-time.

Comment: @DavidHedlund Yeah that was a bit of an extreme example - my point was more to say that behaviour-wise it's not the entirely the same

Answer (score 2):

In `0$1`, the `0` is the literal character `0`.  The `$1` is a reference to a capturing group, ie anything captured by `(\d)`, in your case a single digit.

So as you can see from the output, it's essentially prefixing any single digit captured with `\d` with a `0`.